# Remove duplicates from associative array with multiple columns in PL/SQL

Tags: arrays, oracle

I have seen several great examples of removing duplicates in an Oracle associative array using `MULTISET UNION DISTINCT` and `SET`.  It works great when there is only a single column.
I have an associative array based on a `RECORD` type which contains 3 columns.
Is it possible to use the methods mentioned above?

```
DECLARE
  TYPE rec_type IS RECORD(
     column1 VARCHAR2(5)
    ,column2 VARCHAR2(5));
  TYPE my_aa IS TABLE OF rec_type;
  p_tbl my_aa := my_aa();
  q_tbl my_aa := my_aa();
BEGIN
  p_tbl.extend(4);
  p_tbl(1).column1 := 'A1';
  p_tbl(1).column2 := 'a';
  --
  p_tbl(2).column1 := 'A1';
  p_tbl(2).column2 := 'b';
  --
  p_tbl(3).column1 := 'A1'; -- Dup 
  p_tbl(3).column2 := 'a'; -- Dup
  --
  p_tbl(4).column1 := 'A1';
  p_tbl(4).column2 := 'c';
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('-- First output contains duplicated');
  --
  FOR a IN p_tbl.first .. p_tbl.last LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(a || ' = ' || p_tbl(a).column1 || ' / ' || p_tbl(a).column2);
  END LOOP;
  --
  --
  q_tbl := p_tbl MULTISET UNION DISTINCT p_tbl;
  --
  --
  dbms_output.new_line;
  dbms_output.put_line('-- Duplicates have been removad');
  FOR a IN q_tbl.first .. q_tbl.last LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(a || ' = ' || q_tbl(a).column1|| ' / '||q_tbl(a).column2);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Cant you concat the 3 columns and treat them like 1 col

Comment: I need to de-dup this array as it is designed.  Three columns (the example only shows 2).

Comment: can you build a a duplicate (parallell/shadow) array, that is the 3 columns concated to determine dups, but then only print the "true" array when processing is finished? Good question and well presented, keep posting! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and the advice.  I hadn't considered a concat version.  The down side of that is that I would have to reference two of these things when using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do distinction by `MULTISET UNION DISTINCT` with underlying `RECORD` type due to doc

> The element types of the nested tables must be comparable. Please
>   refer to "Comparison Conditions " for information on the comparability
>   of nonscalar types.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm

Records are not comparable. You can use user defined objects with `MAP` method  for this

> Two objects of nonscalar type are comparable if they are of the same
>   named type and there is a one-to-one correspondence between their
>   elements. In addition, nested tables of user-defined object types,
>   even if their elements are comparable, must have MAP methods defined
>   on them to be used in equality or IN conditions.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions002.htm#i1033286

If you still whant do this with records then try `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM TABLE()` approach, but your types must be defined on schema level for server older than oracle 12c.

Comment: Shucks, so the net-net is, NO I can not use SET or MULTISET UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: Yeah, it is so with `RECORD`